# Python pandas selection - empty dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, selection, dataframe

I try to select data from Pandas dataframe that way:

dane[(dane.Station == 12125) & (dane.Year == 2009) & (dane.Month == 8) & (dane.Day == 1)]

The result is empty dataframe.

The data I try to select exist. Using different paramter values works - I got one cell and index.

The more general code is:

```
dane[category][dane.Station == sibl][dane.Year == y][dane.Month == m][dane.Day == d]
```

With the same bad result on these specific data and good result using different selection parameters (different dates and stations).

What could be wrong with code/data?

Best regards!

> `Index;HrAvg;Lowcloct;Prec;Press;Station;Sund;Tdavg;Temperature Avg;Temperature Max;Temperature Min;Totcloct;Viskm;Wind Int.;Year;Month;Day
>   9468;94.1;5.7;25.0;1008.4;12125.0;1.0;15.0;16.0;19.5;13.6;7.7;8.7;13.5;2009.0;7;19
>   9469;85.7;5.0;2.0;1011.2;12125.0;8.5;13.0;15.5;21.3;10.6;6.0;16.7;13.1;2009.0;7;20
>   9470;76.7;3.0;2.3;1011.8;12125.0;12.8;11.7;16.3;20.6;12.8;3.3;20.0;17.1;2009.0;7;21
>   9471;81.7;4.3;3.0;1008.6;12125.0;0.0;15.5;19.2;27.7;10.7;6.0;13.3;7.7;2009.0;7;22
>   9472;78.9;6.0;12.0;1005.6;12125.0;7.4;18.7;23.1;29.2;17.2;6.3;11.3;9.5;2009.0;7;23
>   9473;76.7;5.0;2.0;1007.9;12125.0;7.3;14.7;19.1;25.9;15.4;6.7;20.0;15.8;2009.0;7;24
>   9474;87.7;6.7;2.2;1012.4;12125.0;5.1;13.7;15.8;19.7;12.4;7.0;16.7;12.6;2009.0;7;25
>   9475;87.1;6.0;18.1;1015.4;12125.0;3.1;12.6;14.8;18.7;12.2;6.0;16.7;15.3;2009.0;7;26
>   9476;74.6;4.0;0.0;1015.6;12125.0;8.1;13.1;18.1;22.7;11.6;6.0;20.0;7.2;2009.0;7;27
>   9477;76.8;4.7;0.5;1016.2;12125.0;4.8;13.8;17.9;21.9;13.7;5.0;16.7;11.3;2009.0;7;28
>   9478;74.3;1.3;0.0;1022.3;12125.0;12.6;12.4;17.7;25.0;10.7;3.0;20.0;8.6;2009.0;7;29
>   9479;74.1;3.7;4.0;1017.4;12125.0;10.2;14.5;19.9;27.1;13.2;4.7;16.7;9.9;2009.0;7;30
>   9480;81.6;4.3;5.0;1020.9;12125.0;8.9;12.0;15.3;19.9;11.3;4.7;14.7;13.1;2009.0;7;31
>   9481;71.2;2.0;0.0;1019.8;12125.0;13.8;10.5;16.3;23.2;9.4;3.0;20.0;9.9;2009.0;8;1
>   9482;66.6;2.7;0.0;1012.8;12125.0;8.5;14.2;21.1;27.4;12.9;5.3;20.0;10.4;2009.0;8;2
>   9483;70.0;5.7;0.0;1011.8;12125.0;7.8;14.5;20.4;25.8;15.4;6.7;20.0;13.1;2009.0;8;3
>   9484;76.8;3.7;0.0;1017.5;12125.0;6.4;14.4;19.0;25.4;14.4;6.7;20.0;10.4;2009.0;8;4
>   9485;89.4;6.0;;1022.1;12125.0;9.8;15.5;16.6;22.5;14.3;6.0;12.5;6.6;2009.0;8;5
>   9486;80.2;3.0;0.0;1023.7;12125.0;12.5;16.0;20.0;25.5;15.1;2.0;14.7;9.0;2009.0;8;6
>   9487;78.1;1.5;0.0;1023.6;12125.0;11.0;14.2;18.7;26.5;12.2;4.3;13.4;6.8;2009.0;8;7
>   9488;71.3;1.5;0.0;1022.4;12125.0;13.6;13.2;19.5;25.9;12.4;1.3;16.7;10.4;2009.0;8;8
>   9489;67.5;1.7;0.0;1021.7;12125.0;11.6;12.6;19.7;26.5;12.4;3.3;20.0;8.1;2009.0;8;9
>   9490;54.3;2.7;0.0;1018.1;12125.0;8.7;10.0;19.9;25.0;15.6;5.7;20.0;10.4;2009.0;8;10
>   9491;78.3;5.3;4.0;1011.8;12125.0;0.0;13.4;17.3;20.7;13.4;6.7;14.7;9.9;2009.0;8;11
>   9492;85.4;6.0;;1010.2;12125.0;4.7;14.4;18.0;19.9;14.3;6.0;20.0;18.0;2009.0;8;12
>   9493;93.2;6.5;;1007.8;12125.0;4.8;14.1;15.9;18.2;13.8;6.5;15.0;13.2;2009.0;8;13
>   9494;80.5;4.7;2.0;1012.8;12125.0;12.0;11.9;15.4;20.2;12.1;5.3;20.0;18.0;2009.0;8;14
>   9495;73.7;7.3;1.1;1016.8;12125.0;1.6;11.4;16.4;21.6;11.1;7.3;16.7;9.9;2009.0;8;15
>   9496;62.7;2.3;0.0;1011.7;12125.0;11.9;13.8;21.4;27.9;16.5;3.3;20.0;14.0;2009.0;8;16`
>
> `dane = pd.DataFrame()
>   dane = pd.read_csv('meteo_clean_fixed.csv', sep=";", na_values=[" ", "---", "----", "-----", "------","Tr"],)
>   tmpval2 = dane[category][dane["Station"] == st][dane.Year == y][dane.Month == m][dane.Day == d]`

where st, y, m, d as in code in question.

Comment: So you're sure that a row exists with that data? Can you post raw input data and code to reproduce this, also your second bit of code smells wrong to me and may not be doing what you think

Comment: Can you post some raw data and code that reproduces your error then as it should work

Comment: Edit into the question, not as a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That specific row has an errant value:

```
In [33]:

dane['Day']
Out[33]:
0    1X
Name: Day, dtype: object
```

This was in the original comment:

```
"""Index;HrAvg;Lowcloct;Prec;Press;Station;Sund;Tdavg;Temperature Avg;Temperature Max;Temperature Min;Totcloct;Viskm;Wind Int.;Year;Month;Day
9481;71.2;2.0;0.0;1019.8;12125.0;13.8;10.5;16.3;23.2;9.4;3.0;20.0;9.9;2009.0;8;1X"""
```

Which is not in your posted data in your question.

Comment: Hey @EdChum
thanks for yor help!
I made some corrections in script preparing these data and now  it seems to be ok :-) Thanks again ;